# c# use of class property as argument in a simpler way

Tags: c#, reflection

I have a method that works OK to get the index of a list using a class property as argument.

The code:

```
public static int GetIndex<T, TKey>(this T myTypeClass, Expression<Func<T, TKey>> propertySelector)
{
    var body = (MemberExpression)propertySelector.Body;
    var propertyInfo = (PropertyInfo)body.Member;

    // list where I need to find the index for the property defined in the argument
    List<KeyValuePair<PropertyInfo, int>> indexList = GlobalClassList;

    // simple LINQ line to retrieve the int that corresponds with the 'propertyInfo'
    int i = indexList.FindIndex(p => p.Key.Equals(propertyInfo));
    return i;
}
```

To call the method:

```
MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
myClass.GetIndex(c=>c.property)
```

What I'm trying to do, is to simplify the argument in the method using just the property of the class (`c.property`) instead having to rely on the use of the `Expression<Func<T, TKey>>` (`c=>c.property`).
Is this possible?

Comment: I would like to correct something: using `myClass.property` or `MyClass.property` is the goal.

Comment: No, I don't think that syntax is posible with properties as it could be with methods; The syntax would be ambigous; no way to differentiate from a simple property call.

Comment: I was just trying to minimize the amount that I have to right just to get a simple integer. Anyway, Many Thanks for your feedback.